# Is it possible for users to interact without querying the backend?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am essentially building an App that enables people to score a given image. This scoring happens over an hour, during which the UI label representing the average score is being updated after each user scores. Is there a way to enable this interactive space where people can score, see what others have scored, and the label to be updated accordingly. Then when the time is up, save it to Parse as opposed to constantly saving data and querying the backend...seems unnecessarily clunky. thanks.

Comment: You want to have synchronized data over multiple devices/users without up- and downloading? This is somehow weird, that's what the backend is there for, no? Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: yeah pretty much - so is the backend the only / most efficient way of doing that. i was thinking because its going to be a dynamic space that would require a lot of querying. is there not an SDK that could handle that? so for example, facebook's messenger SDK allows people to converse. i'm looking for something similar, but not allowing messages to be sent and instead customised buttons. is this not possible?

Comment: You could use Firebase? It's a backend where you don't have to manually query for changes, but you add observers to your data (which is on the servers) and those observers tell you when the data has changed, when new data is available, etc. With Parse, you would have to do a lot of querying, so, for your case, Parse is maybe not ideal, depending on how often you want to update the data.

Comment: thanks mate I will look into that sounds very useful. quite annoying there isnt a way for users to interact in the virtual space without the backend!

Comment: Why is this annoying? Your virtual space IS your backend, that's the intended use case of your backend. You just need a more dynamic backend like e.g. Firebase for that case, which is for very dynamic databases. Parse is great for more static data. You could use Firebase as your "virtual space" and then use Parse as the final storage system.